# How to only allow emails in my array to be able to sign up for an account

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, authorization

I'm creating an app for work that has to have user authentication. However, I only want certain emails to be able to sign up and access the app. I have an array set to the specific emails and I'm trying to loop through the array and if req.body doesn't match any emails in the array, then return an error.

For this question, I supplied emailArray with placeholder emails. In the actual app, I have the emails in a .env file and then I place the env variables into the array.

I'm trying to loop through the array with a for loop but this isn't working. When I try to hit this route in postman with an email in the array, I still get the error "Invalid Email"

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Maybe a for loop isn't the way to approach this. Any advice on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

I'm using sequelize for this app. I'll supply the model, route and server file below the picture incase those will help anybody solve the problem.

```
createUser: async (req, res) => {

        const { email, password } = req.body;

        const emailArray = ["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com", "email3@email.com", "email4@email.com"]
        try {

            for (let i = 0; i < emailArray.length; i++) {

                if (email !== emailArray[i]) {

                    return res.status(401).json("Invalid Email");
                };

            }

            const newUser = await Users.create({ email, password });

            res.json(newUser);


        } catch (error) {

            console.error(error.message);
            return res.status(500).json(error);

        };
    }
```

[image]

Model

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Users extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Users.init({
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Users',
    tableName: 'users',
    timestamps: false
  });
  return Users;
};
```

Route

```
const router = require('express').Router();

const usersController = require("../controllers/users");

router.post('/register', usersController.createUser);

module.exports = router
```

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config()

const { sequelize } = require('./models');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const app = express();

//Handlebars Middleware
app.engine(
  "handlebars",
  exphbs({
    defaultLayout: "main",
    runtimeOptions: {
      allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
      allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true,
    },
  })
);

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Express Middleware
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//Express Route
app.use('/', require('./routes/users'));

app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
  await sequelize.sync();
  console.log('Database connection established');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because in for loop, first iteration you check the validity of email - it returns the error and breaks

```js
createUser: async (req, res) => {

        const { email, password } = req.body;

        const emailArray = ["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com", "email3@email.com", "email4@email.com"]
        try {
            const isValid = emailArray.includes(req.body.email)
            if (!isValid) {
                return res.status(401).json("Invalid Email");
            }

            const newUser = await Users.create({ email, password });

            res.json(newUser);


        } catch (error) {

            console.error(error.message);
            return res.status(500).json(error);

        };
    }
```